# how to get content type in views-view.html.twig files | drupal 8

Tags: twig, content-type, drupal-views, drupal-8

I have a view in which I show several content types so I need to filter some custom menu entries that I've made in "views-view--myview.html.twig" based on the content type that is shown in the current view.

I've used xdebug but cannot print the content type machine name in my view (I need the content type machine name, not the label!)

Please note that I don't want to do that in the views-view-fields template.

My question is: How can I get the content type (that is shown in a view) in the views-view.html.twig file?

If there is a preprocess function it would also help me!

Comment: Interesting first question buddy. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2):

in *views-view.html.twig* or overriden twig such as *views-view--myview.html.twig* you can do the following

get title of first row entity

```
{{rows[0]['#rows'][0]['#row']._entity.getTitle()}}
```

get type/bundle of first row entity

```
{{rows[0]['#rows'][0]['#row']._entity.bundle()}}
```

So to access all rows you probably need a loop 
following checks the entity type/bundle for each row

```
{% for row in rows[0]['#rows'] %}  
    {% if row['#row']._entity.bundle() == 'page' %}
      <div>its a page</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But perhaps the best place to modify individual rows of a view is inside a specific display of a view such as *views-view-unformatted.html.twig* or *views-view-unformatted--myview.html.twig*

for comparison get title and type/bundle and looping through rows as above

```
{{rows[0]['content']['#row']._entity.getTitle()}}
{{rows[0]['content']['#row']._entity.bundle()}}

{% for row in rows %}
  {% if row['content']['#row']._entity.bundle() == 'page' %}
    <div>its a page</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Don't know why the questioner didn't accept this answer but for me it worked :) ... but How we access the fields?